# Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have two apis to consume. First api will give me list of Exercises. I then need to use ids from all of these exercises to get images for the exercises.

Following are my models:

```
    public struct ExerciseItem: Hashable {
    public let id: Int
    public let name: String
    public let exerciseInfo: ExerciseInfoItem?
    
}
public struct ExerciseInfoItem: Hashable {
    let images: [String]?
    let description: String?
    
    public init(
        images: [String]?,
        description: String?
    ) {
        self.images = images
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

I am trying to get these values as following:

```
let aaa = interactor.getExerciseList().flatMap { entities -> AnyPublisher<[ExerciseItem], Error> in
        let ex = entities.map { exitem in
            self.interactor.getExerciseInfo(id: exitem.id)
        }
        return Publishers.MergeMany(ex).collect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }.sink { completion in
        
    } receiveValue: { ee in
        
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

I am getting following error in last line of my code:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

My ultimate goal is to get list of exercises and display it in UITableview with placeholder for images and when I start receiving image urls asynchronously display it in the tableview.

Comment: You would probably be better off using something like SDWebImage or Swift Concurrency to fetch the images directly from the cell

Comment: yes I will do that but to get the url of the image I need to call a second api with id received from first api

Comment: Use Swift Concurrency if you can

Comment: The compiler is having a hard time understanding the types of something in your code.  In my experience it's usually the parameters to closures.  For example the `ee` in your `receiveValue` closure.  Try giving explicit type annotations to those for example `{ (ee: [ExerciseItem]) in ...`